# Do US Series I Savings Bonds have CUSIPs?

Tags: united-states, bonds, cusip

Do Series I Savings Bonds ("I-bonds") have CUSIPs? If so, how can I find the CUSIP for my electronically-purchased I-bonds?

The TreasuryDirect website has [information about some recent auctions with associated CUSIPs](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/instit.htm), but I'm not sure whether any of the things auctioned there are I-bonds. (I seem to remember reading that I-bonds [unlike TIPS] aren't sold at auction. Is that right?)

(Context: I'm trying to manually enter my I-bond holdings on Personal Capital. To have them properly sorted by asset class, it looks like I need to know the CUSIPs for my bonds.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Saving Bonds data](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/annceresult_slgssb.htm) is available at the Treasury direct website. 
I don't think these get CUSIPs since they are not traded in secondary market.

Comment: Ah, crud. That makes sense - no point in having a CUSIP for something that isn't traded on the secondary market. Maybe I should switch to TIPS...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your immediate question is no, they don't have CUSIPs since they aren't traded on the secondary market, and TIPS will not reflect the true value either since I-Bonds and TIPS are different investments that will differ in growth rate over time.

Note that you can still manually record the I-Bonds as US bonds in Personal Capital, the values just won't be automatically updated for you.

Steps as of November 2021:

1. Add a new account of type "Manual Investment Holdings" to your portfolio, example values of Firm Name: "Treasury Direct", Account Name: "I-Bonds", Account Type: "Investment (non-retirement)"
2. Select the account and scroll to the holdings section
3. Click "Add Holding", enter Ticker/CUSIP: "I-BOND", Description: "I-Bonds", Shares: the dollar amount purchased, Price: $1, and click Done
4. Navigate to Investing -> Allocation, and click on the "Manual Classifications" button
5. Select "I-BOND" and allocate it to 100% US Bonds -> 100% Government Bonds, save your changes

You'll now be able to track your I-Bonds under your bond allocation, while you'll need to manually make updates to reflect growth from interest payments.